# translating a ruby script to python

Tags: python

my problem is the following

i have a ruby script looking like this

```
module parent

    module son_1
        ... some code here
    end

    module son_2
        ... some code here
    end

    class one
        ... some code here
    end

    class two
        ... some code here
    end

end
```

and i need this script to be translated to python but
i am little confused ?

first i made this :

- i turned the "module parent" into a python package
- i made "module son_1" and "module son_2" like two files inside the package
- and finally i defined the last two classed in the `__init__` file of this package ( "module parent" )

my questions are :

- is this solution correct ?
- and if it is , is there a better one ?

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this on the file system :

```
- parent/
  ------- __init__.py << empty file or can have classes if you need, that way python will treat parent as a package
  ------- son_1.py
  ------- son_2.py
- test.py
```

then in actual code in test.py :

```
from parent import son_1, son_2, one, two
c = one('something')
b = son_1.something()
#or
import parent
import parent.son_1
import parent.son_2
c = parent.one('something')
b = parent.son_1.something()
```